# text overflow in block content

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I want to make a simple blog that shows the details of a post when a user clicks a title in a list of new posts on an index page. However, I realized that my detail of post shows overflow in my block `mycontent`, this is what I did:

base.html has a line like this:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    {% block mycontent %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

my read_post.html

```
{% block mycontent %}
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <code>{{ post.publish }}</code><br>
    {{ post.content|linebreaks }}
{% endblock %}
```

This is my result when I have long text, I want it to have a newline and to not overflow from block mycontent. I am using boostrap for theme site

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there is such a long word ?  Anyway, you can do `word-wrap: break-word;` to break this long word to the next line

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  `word-wrap: break-word` property?

```
- Word-wrap allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line
- break-word allows unbreakable words to be broken
```